# how to keep on adding the recent score in achievement in a game

Tags: android, google-play-games, leaderboard

I am developing a game in which I want to keep on adding the current played score to the previous played score.

Example if my previous score is 10 and my current score is 20 then I want the leaderboard will show 30 as my score.

But my problem is every time I push my score only the the highest score is displayed in leaderboard.

I am submitting score using this code.

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, LEADERBOARD_ID, 20);
```

What should I do?Is this really possible.

Comment: Yes it is possible. First get the previous `highScore` as `int`, I presume `LEADERBOARD_ID` is previous highScore, and the current score as `int` and add the together before you submit it to `mGoogleApuClient`

Comment: Is this a right approach? I  was also thinking about the same.

Comment: It is the simplest way of doing it. Get current update with highest and store. No need for sharedpreferences

Comment: well thanks for answering I am going to use this approach only.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving it with SharedPreferences like this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit(); 
editor.putInt("score", 20);
editor.apply();
```

And then get the last score again like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredScore= prefs.getInt("score", 0);

if (restoredScore != 0) {
  // do something with the score
}else{
  // the score did not exist
}
```

More on SharedPreferences here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: what if the player clear all the data from the application

Comment: @ApplicationFan  Add on the game start up to check for the score and set a default if there is no score, that way there would always be a score even if the player clears all the data

Comment: Is there any other way that I simply add scores and it will be added in leaderboard (any settings in developer console) cause i don't think SharedPreferences will work.

Comment: You should DEFINITELY not use `SharedPreferences` it is bad practice using `SharedPreferences` for stuff like this and it is unnecessary.

Comment: @H.Brooks provide links and posts to prove that claim

Comment: @Vincent please provide a reason why he should store it in SharedPreferences? He doesn't need to store anything accept what he is sending to `mGoogleApiClient`.